# A word for extreme care, attention, dedication towards words or a language

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, connotation

I'm looking for a word or a phrase which suggests the treatment of words or a language with extreme care, attention, and devotion -- like on StackExchange for example.

I thought of **pamper** e.g. words are pampered on this site. But I think the word pamper carries a rather negative connotation. I'm looking for a word with positive undertones.

Comment: In precise and well-articulated argument he made the case for the defendant.

Comment: _Fastidious_ - but I can't think of a word that is specifically about words and language.

Comment: You may find your way to a word or phrase if you try to articulate the *purpose* of the care and attention. A person might be deeply concerned that those who use a language be able to express themselves clearly and understand what others are saying and writing. Or a person might have a fascination with the way languages work.

Comment: When I want to note that I respect someone's efforts and ability, I often say that person is a *careful* writer.

Comment: I comprehend a predilection for obscure polysyllabic xenolocutions :). I was always taught to eschew obfuscation, so I'm curious about the -2 score for the two-syllable word ***nurture***, which is a synonym of **pamper** ( a verb suggested by the OP), and contains, in its definition, the lead modifier in the OP question as well as connotations of the other modifiers in the OP question. Requesting comments from the down-voters, or a rally to the reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

[Logophilia](http://www.yourdictionary.com/logophilia):

> - The love of words.

[Logophile](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Logophile): (from TFD)

> - One who appreciates and enjoys words.
>
>   - Someone who loves words is called a [logophile](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/what-s-someone-who-loves-words-called). Despite there being quite a
>       few of us word-lovers, logophile is not common enough to find its way into
>       most dictionaries. Logophile comes from two Greek roots--logos, meaning
>       "speech, word, reason" and philos, meaning "dear, friendly"--and these
>       roots have also played a part in other more common English words.
>   - Logos is part of the history of the words analogous, apology, and
>       logic. And philos gave us the noun combining form -phile, meaning
>       "someone who likes something very much."

( from M-W)

Answer (score 2):

About treatment of words or a language ....

> **[Glossophilia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossophilia)** is a love of language, be it *foreign or native*.
>
> The term refers to people with a love for language and the structure
>   of language.

Comment: I believe the overwhelming connotation of Glossophilia is spoken language.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term **linguaphile** is possibly the closest single-word description. It embraces the extreme care, attention and dedication that are described - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/linguaphile.

Answer (score -1):

***[Nurture](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nurture)*** could take the place of pamper without its rather negative connotations.

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 **Care for** and **protect** (someone or something) while it is
>   **growing**:
>
> 1.1 **Help** or **encourage** the development of:
>
> 1.2 **Cherish** (a hope, belief, or ambition):
>
> NOUN
>
> 1 The process of caring for and encouraging the growth or development
>   of someone or something:

In all three senses of the expression:

**StackExchange** *nurtures* words and language.

Language is constantly *growing* in our minds as well as in our culture. Someone must *care for* and *protect* the **words**.  Someone must *care for*, *protect* and *encourage* the delicate **relationships** between and around the words of our language. Someone must *help* the ignorant to *cultivate* their language skills, because the power of a language is diminished by the ignorance of those who abuse it. We *cherish* the grammar, the words, and the very ideas that generate and regenerate our language every day, because our language *nurtures* the relationship between us!

> ORIGIN
>
> Middle English: from Old French *noureture 'nourishment',* based on
>   Latin *nutrire '**feed**, cherish'.*

In *nourishing* our language, we *feed* ourselves, for language is the pure essence of the human spirit, the sweet nectar of the human mind.

**Connotations of *Nurture*:**

- **Care for**
- **Protect**
- **Cherish**
- **Nourish**
- **Cultivate**

  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nurture

***Emphasis*** is mine to imply connotations.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers have provided nouns referring to "a love of language" and verbs denoting "pampering," so I'd like to provide some adjectives that I believe convey the "extreme care and attention" (and thus, one might say, the "devotion") to which you refer in your question:

> **fastidious**: very attentive to and concerned about accuracy and detail.
>
> "He chooses his words with fastidious care."
>
> **scrupulous**: (of a person or process) diligent, thorough, and extremely attentive to details.
>
> "The research has been carried out with scrupulous attention to detail."

NB: Colin Fine, a fine and fastidious user himself, suggested the former in a comment. Props.

Granted, these two words are not used exclusively to refer to care and attention to language, but (as the example for fastidious shows) they can certainly be used in this context.

Of course, there are adjectives that describe those whose fastidiousness and scrupulousness with language (combined with an artistry that results from devotion) produces good speech and writing:

> **articulate**: expressing oneself in clear and effective language.
>
> **eloquent:** fluent or persusasive in speaking or writing; clearly expressing or indicating something.